# How to format radiobuttonlist in c# with image included programmatically

Tags: c#, dynamically-generated

I'm little confused with how RadioButtonList works dynamically when it comes to styling it.
Basically what I wanted to achieve is something really simple : Image on top and a new line would be the name of that image plus the radiobutton beside it.[image]

something like the above.

I have the following code and it doesn't do it.

```
  foreach(var m in models){ tmpRBL.Items.Add(new ListItem(string.Format("{0}<img src='{1}' width='120' height='120' style='padding:5px;'/><br/>",m.name.Substring(0,15), s.Image_Path_Large + m.ImageID + ".jpg"), m.ModelID.ToString()));}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why don't you try to use `Repeater` Control instead on `RadioButtonList` because you can easily apply desired `Template` to your `View`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use following code:

```
 foreach (var filename in Images)
    {
        file = new System.IO.FileInfo(filename);

        item = new ListItem("<img src='{1}' width='120' height='120' style='padding:5px;'/><br/>", i.ToString());

        RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(item);

        i++;
    }
}
```